# Tree traversal in python how to determine parent node after printing child node

Tags: python, binary-tree

In the following code the tree has 5 elements  ,where A has (B,C) and B has (D,E), my question is after printing the last element ,and that node is D how does the node switches to 'B' in the following code,can some one explain this code please

```
class trees(object):
    def __init__(self,name,left=None,right=None):
            self.name = name
            self.left = None
            self.right = None

def inorderTraversal(root):
     res = []
     if root:
            res = inorderTraversal(root.left) 
            print root.name
            res = res + inorderTraversal(root.right)

t1=trees('A')
t2=trees('B')
t3=trees('C')
t4=trees('D')
t5=trees('E')

t1.left = t2
t1.right = t3
t2.left= t4
t2.right = t5

inorderTraversal(t1) 
#prints D,B,E,A,C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion).

Instead of, what happens after 'B' is printed you should rather think of what happens before 'B' is printed.

Let's consider the root `t2`right before the node that contains 'B'.(Maybe you could even reduce your tree to only contain t2, t4 and t5. This should be more instructive). What happens next is the following:

1. inordertraversal to t4 which is the left child of t2. Eventually, this will print 'D'
2. print 'B'
3. inordertraversal to t5 which is the right child of t2. Eventually, this will print 'E'

afterwards, we move to the parent of t2 etc.

Note that for trees without children the root is printed since for its children `root is None`evaluates to false. Thus nothing happens on the children level and we traverse up to the root, print its name, and travere down to its child where nothing happens again.

---

Regarding your comment: Your code ensures that when you print 'D' you will also print 'B' afterwards due to recursion!

Let's assume we only have the tree (t2, (t4, t5)) and we call `inorderTraversal(t2)`:
What happens (after removing the unnecessary res):

1. Start at t2

   ```
   if t2: (True)
       inorderTraversal(t4)
       print 'B'
       inorderTraversal(t5)
   ```
2. execute inorderTraversal(t4) and resolve if(t2)

   ```
   if t4 (True):
          inorderTraversal(None)
          print 'D'
          inorderTraversal(None) 

   print 'B'
   inorderTraversal(t5)
   ```

Let's see what the term in the curly brackets is doing:
The inorderTraversal(None) just do noting, so the only thing that happens here is that the name of t4 is printed. 
So you see, that the print 'B' appears earlier than print 'D'

3. Let's summarize the recursive call once more

   ```
   print 'D' 
   print 'B'
   inorderTraversal(t5)
   ```

Comment: After printing 'D' the root is now t4, but how will 'B' be printed.i.e, when does the change happen to t2 now in your point 2

Comment: Added another example with code. However, are you really familiar with recursion? That's the only thing happening here

Comment: I think that's now how recursion works. You don't call the traverse function on t2 again but execute the commands only on its child. So t2, doesn't see that its left and right child are `None`, cause they aren't. Btw, you should get rid of res since it absolutely does nothing and maybe makes things more complicated

Comment: done, note that I used that inorderTraversal(None) just does nothing! So in the 3rd step, we can print 'D' and 'B' and afterwards we need to traverse to t4.